# Optimal place to call __syncthreads()

Tags: c++, cuda

Given that the code is correct, is there some potential performance benefit in calling `__syncthreads` as late as possible, as early as possible, or does it not matter? Here's an example with comments that demonstrate the question:

```
__global__ void kernel(const float* data) {
    __shared__ float shared_data[64];

    if (threadIdx.x < 64) {
        shared_data[threadIdx.x] = data[threadIdx.x];
    }
    // Option #1: Place the call to `__syncthreads()` here?

    // Here is a lot of code that doesn't use `shared_data`.

    // Option #2: Place the call to `__syncthreads()` here?

    // Here is some code that uses `shared_data`.
}
```

Comment: I don't know, but my guess would be to use it as late as possible, only where needed. Have you tried/timed it? In general, let the compiler do the job, it may not even matter .

Comment: No I haven't tried benchmarking it (I'm in the process of learning CUDA so I'm unable to do that just yet).

Comment: Note: Architecture 8.0 (Ampere) introduced asynchronous memory copies from global to shared memory and also more sophisticated memory barriers: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#aw-barrier Those barriers allow to mark, where the data has been written and were it is needed with separate commands, with the new hardware being able to use this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are facing is a split between where the writes are made and where they should be visible to the entire block.

NVIDIA has recently introduced a mechanism for just that: arrive + wait.

You start with initializing a barrier:

```
void __mbarrier_init(__mbarrier_t* bar, uint32_t expected_count);
```

Then you arrive at your "option 1" position, with the bar token you initialized:

```
__mbarrier_token_t __mbarrier_arrive(__mbarrier_t* bar);
```

then you have your unrelated code, and then finally, wait for *everyone* to arrive at your "option 2" position:

```
bool __mbarrier_test_wait(__mbarrier_t* bar, __mbarrier_token_t token);
```

... but note that this call doesn't block, i.e you'll have to actively "wait".

Alternatively, you can use NVIDIA's C++ wrappers for this mechanism, presented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#temporal_split_5_stage_sync).

Note that this functionality is relatively new, with Compute Capability at least 7.0 required, and 8.0 or later recommended.